# Question moved on SO when i'm asking only about security risks

Tags: support

First i hope that my question isn't off topic here, i'm sorry if it's the case but i don't know where i should ask if it's not here.

I'm asking a question about security risks and what i should do when adding a particular fonctionnality, yet my post has been moved to SO without any comments of why it should belong to SO. But cleary it doesn't belong to SO, i'm not asking for any code.

Maybe my question wasn't well explained. Can you take a look at it and explained me why wouldn't it belong to security SE ?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35713409/security-risk-of-a-service-that-test-connection-from-server-for-a-printer-from-c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand why it was closed - the question seems very unclear. I read it a number of times and am not sure what you are asking. But I'm not sure why it was moved to SO. It's still unclear there...

One thing to remember is that the system takes the majority view on closing, so there may have been 4 different Vote to Close reasons, or all the same - impossible to tell.

Comment: My question is about security risks. When a user add a printer on my application, i want to add an action to perform a connection test from the server to the printer and i'm wondering about any security risks there.

Comment: I edited my question, i think i described too much the UI part, so i removed this and focused on the security part and the functionnality, i hope my question is more clear now.

Comment: @Walfrat did you edit it on SO or here on Sec.SE? Because good news is it was rejected from SO, so its back here - but any edits you did over there are lost... :-(

Comment: @AviD it's edited back to what it was on SO :)

Comment: My question is back here and got edited to be more clear by someone else, i'm validating your answer to close the topic. Guess my post was just too messy when i asked first

Comment: Excellent - I spoke with the mods over on SO and agreed it should be sent back here.

Answer (score 1):

I'm one of the folks who voted to move it to SO.  In in initial version of the question, it appeared to me that your primary question was about adding a button to your application to test a printer.   It was somewhat unclear, but the security component appeared to me to be peripheral, and I thought I understood the question well enough to determine that the core was about making the button work, a programming question.   In hindsight, I didn't understand correctly, and I should have let you clarify the question first, rather than voting to move.  Mea culpa.

Comment: Yeah the title was "Adding a buttton... " and the first sentence was "i'm" wondering about security risks ...". This is why i edited my title as well. I thought that the original title may have lead to that downvote. Guess there is no point talking about what will look like the UI there, adding my bad english, this is fatal :)